# MongoDB sort by Array order

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

let say I have documents

```
[
  {
    score : 3,
  },
  {
    score : 1,
  },
  {
    score : 2,
  }
]
```

and an array contain order of score

```
const array = [2,1,3]
```

How can I sort documents by order of array

expected result :

```
[
  {
    score : 2,
  },
  {
    score : 1,
  },
  {
    score : 3,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [indexOfArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        "order": {
            $indexOfArray: [[2,1,3], "$score"]
        }
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        "order": 1
    }
}
]);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ig74L8xKm0U)